# Powershell get LDAP display name from Active Directory without AD privileges

Tags: vb.net, powershell, active-directory, ldap

I am rewriting a login script from VB to PowerShell and I need the LDAP display name to be exported to a log file. The problem is that I, as well as many other users, do not have permissions to use any commands such as `get-aduser` and the like. I do have access to the `ADSystemInfo` object, but that does not seem to have the desired information.

The VB code to get the info looks like this:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)
strFullName = objUser.Get("Displayname")
```

The format of the vb output of strFullname looks something like:

```
'lastname, firstname middleinitial (plus a bit of other ad info)'.
```

In PowerShell, I can get the `strUser`, but I am unsure how to translate the last couple of the lines.

```
$adsysinfo = New-Object -ComObject "ADSystemInfo"
$strUser = $adsysinfo.GetType().InvokeMember("username", "GetProperty", $Null, $adsysinfo, $Null) -split ',' | select -first 1 
$strUser = $strUser -split('=') | select -last 1
```

There are other scripts which mine the log file i am outputting to, so I need to keep formatting exact. Solutions on google only recommend using `get-aduser`, which again I can't use here. Can anyone help me translate those last 2 VB lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are 90% there, you simply need to translate the last bit into an `[adsi]` object, and use it like an object.

```
$adsysinfo = New-Object -ComObject "ADSystemInfo"

#Get Distinguished Name
$strUser = $adsysinfo.GetType().InvokeMember("username", "GetProperty", $Null, $adsysinfo, $Null)

#Get ADSI object from LDAP query
$objUser = [adsi]"LDAP://$strUser"

#Reference ADSI object to pull Display Name
$strFullName = $objUser.displayName
```